# Car parked on an infinite street: find car and compute the complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

Here is the question asked at an Interview:

You are placed on a street which is very long. This is the street that you parked your car at. You have to find your car on this street.

What is the algorithm to find your car and what is the complexity. The answer they were looking for was O(nlogn)...but you have to prove why is it is o(nlogn)...
hint: lot of math involved to get to this answer.

Comment: if street is infinite, where's guarantee that we'll find the car? E.g., if you looked at first N slots, car still can be at N+1 slot, with N unbounded.

Comment: This is not at all a complete question. What operations are allowed? What is `n`, since the street is supposedly infinite?

Comment: either you misheard the question or the interviewer is trying to trick you into giving an "answer"

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: that's how I figured out what the question is ;) See my answer.

Comment: What kind of world is this? Unlimited resources to build infinite roads, but still I have no device which can locate my car? Some people seem to try too hard to embed abstract mathematical problems into the real world.

Comment: @Dougal I changed the problem to state a long (finite) street instead of infinite street

Comment: @reima That was my question when I was asked this same question. I don't it matters that much as to whether one can build an infinite road or not. I believe they were looking for the approach

Comment: @reima I think the point was to purposely make it convoluted so someone unfamiliar with the math aspect wouldn't be able to relate to it and would therefore get weeded out, they wanted someone who recognized that it was a math problem right off.

Comment: @Masti arbitrarily long and infinite are functionally equivalent in this context... Ok, so it's "very long". But where does "very long" bleed into infinite? Try and name a bound for "very long". Now try and name a bound for infinite. Did you have the same answer?

Answer (score 5):

I guess `n` here is the distance to the car. The problem is that you're in the middle of an infinite street/line and you don't know in which direction to go.

A solution for this is to go x units in one direction, then 2x to the other, then 4x in forward, 8x in reverse direction etc... And the needed walk is <strike>O(n*logn)</strike> O(n).

Comment: Can you explain how you got to O(nlogn) though?

Comment: If this is right, I did figure the algorithm correctly.. I need to bone up on my big O notation chops though.

Comment: m + m/2 + m/4 + m/8 .... ~ m * logm. the last distance you cover is less than 2n, so asymptotically this is still correct.

Comment: One should prove that we guaranteed to find a car, before stating a number of turns needed to complete search.

Comment: @Victor Sorokin: good point. at any point you went 1x + 4x + 16x... in one direction, and 2x+ 8x + 32x .. in the other. one is the double of the other, and the distance increases exponentially...

Comment: Perhaps, interviewer meant "very long street" and not "infinite".

Comment: @Victor Sorokin: I think it's safe to assume that the car is in finite distance, as you parked it ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath actually, `m + m/2 + m/4+...` = the sum from n=1 to infinity of `m / (2^ (n - 1))`. That would converge to 2m.

Comment: @Phillip Schmidt: mmm right... I think I should sleep :/ (updated answer).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that in it's current state, this question can't be answered, even based off of the assumptions from your answer.

Comment: In fact, I'm positive it can't be answered. It can be mathematically *proven* that it can't be answered. Either there's a lot more to the question or the interviewer was being an a-hole. Either way, I wish the op would come back and clarify.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Isn't this -n...n and not 1...n? Reason been you are starting from a point an then moving back and forth by n^2?

Comment: Well, I think I was mistaken, it's possible to reach any fixed slot, it's just impossible to visit all slots on infinite street. Really, Karoly's pointed this well -- "car is parked by me, so it must be reachable".

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the online [cow path problem](http://web.mit.edu/jaillet/www/general/online-or.pdf).  The usual metric is the worst case travel distance compared with the distance you would travel if you knew where the car was ([competitive ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_analysis_%28online_algorithm%29)).  This is 9n, which is actually O(n), not O(n log n). You do, however make O(log n) changes of direction.